# How to get the new JavaScript object from two object with the keys and average on values when keys match

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

For example, I have two objects:

```
let firstObject = 
 {
   'x' : 3,
   'y' : 2,
   'z' : 1
 }

let secondObject = 
 {
   'x' : 1,
   'y' : 5,
   'c' : 3
 }
```

Is it possible to get the new object with all keys from both objects and count average on both values when keys are matched, so the new object would look like this?

```
newObject = 
 {
   'x' : 2,     // ((3+1)/2)
   'y' : 3.5,   // ((2+5)/2)
   'z' : 1,     // z only in one object, so do nothing and just add to new objects with key : value
   'c' : 3      // c only in one object, so do nothing and just add to new objects with key : value 
 }
```

Values of the keys are always > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Object.entries and forEach.  Mutates first object.  Depends on undefined + n being NaN which is falsy, so || will use the second value.

```js
let firstObject = 
 {
   'x' : 3,
   'y' : 2,
   'z' : 1
 }

let secondObject = 
 {
   'x' : 1,
   'y' : 5,
   'c' : 3
 } 
 
 Object.entries(secondObject).forEach(([k,v])=>firstObject[k]=(firstObject[k]+v)/2||v)
 
 console.log(firstObject)
```